# Error when Spring Cloud Kinesis app is stopped

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

I have a Spring Boot app with the Spring Cloud binder for Kinesis. Everything works fine, but when I stop the app I get the following exception:

```
2020-11-23 18:40:36.292  INFO  --- [extShutdownHook] a.i.k.KinesisMessageDrivenChannelAdapter : stopped KinesisMessageDrivenChannelAdapter{shardOffsets=[KinesisShardOffset{iteratorType=TRIM_HORIZON, sequenceNumber='null', timestamp=null, stream='product-master-data-updated-event-stream', shard='shardId-000000000000', reset=false}], consumerGroup='marketing-campaign'}
2020-11-23 18:40:36.299 ERROR  --- [s-shard-locks-1] a.i.k.KinesisMessageDrivenChannelAdapter : ShardConsumerManager Thread [org.springframework.integration.aws.inbound.kinesis.KinesisMessageDrivenChannelAdapter$ShardConsumerManager@71bd846d] has been interrupted

java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.integration.aws.inbound.kinesis.KinesisMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.sleep(KinesisMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:668)
    at org.springframework.integration.aws.inbound.kinesis.KinesisMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.access$1400(KinesisMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.integration.aws.inbound.kinesis.KinesisMessageDrivenChannelAdapter$ShardConsumerManager.run(KinesisMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:1431)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

I'm using

```
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis:2.0.3.RELEASE'
springBoot: "2.2.7.RELEASE",
```

**How can I stop the app gracefully?** An exception on every deployment doesn't look nice.

Answer (score 1):

The exception is just logged under `ERROR` level. You can move it for now to the `FATAL` logging level for that `a.i.k.KinesisMessageDrivenChannelAdapter` category.

We just need to fix this `KinesisMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.ShardConsumerManager` to avoid exception logging and rethrowing when the channel adapter is already in a stopped state.

Feel free to raise a GH issue and we will see what and how we can fix over there.

The thread interruption in that logic is correct behavior and should not effect anything in your application.

**UPDATE**

Related GH issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-aws/issues/187